# namenode datanode and sec name node not getting started when i hit jps command

Tags: hadoop

I was using Hadoop 1.2.1 in a pseudo-distributed mode in Ubuntu and everything was working fine. But then I had to restart my system . And now when I am hit jps command after giving start-all.sh i was able to see only tasktracker and jobtracker running. Could anyone tell me the possible reason of this problem? and guide me getting this resolved?

```
************************************************************/
2017-03-13 18:41:16,733 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = keerthana-VirtualBox/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.2.1
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2 -r 1503152; compiled by 'mattf' on Mon Jul 22 15:23:09 PDT 2013
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_121
************************************************************/
2017-03-13 18:41:19,383 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2017-03-13 18:41:19,628 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2017-03-13 18:41:19,653 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2017-03-13 18:41:19,653 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode metrics system started
2017-03-13 18:41:21,947 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2017-03-13 18:41:22,117 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2017-03-13 18:41:23,564 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Invalid directory in dfs.data.dir: Incorrect permission for /home/keerthana/hadoop/dfs/data, expected: rwxr-xr-x, while actual: rwxrwxr-x
2017-03-13 18:41:23,564 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: All directories in dfs.data.dir are invalid.
2017-03-13 18:41:23,564 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exiting Datanode
2017-03-13 18:41:23,630 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at keerthana-VirtualBox/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

Comment: Can you tell us the logs that are being generated ?
The data node and the name node logs ?

Comment: now my name node is working fine.but still facing issues with data node.I have attached datanode log for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested from the logs, there are some problems with the dfs.data.dir "**/home/keerthana/hadoop/dfs/data**" location.

Provide check if the folder exists or not and whether they have the proper permission or not. If folder exists , then provide 755 access for that folder.

chmod -R 755 **/home/keerthana/hadoop/dfs/data**

Comment: Hi Deepan i tried the above and it worked perfectly ... thanks a lot :) .But Could you please tel me y such scenario happened? Bcoz i haven created any dedicated user for hadoop and have created both directories for name node and data node at the same time with sudo mkdir command.

Comment: Yes,the user running the hadoop daemon should have entire access for writing the logs. If you have any dedicated user, that would definitely solve the problem.
Can you please accept the answer and up-vote it.